# How to increase max upload image size to 16M in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, category, php-7, image-upload, htaccess

I modify the field values `upload_max_filesize = 20M` ,`post_max_size = 20M` and `memory_limit = 2048M`in the PHP.ini file of the server.

I have to upload the banner images up to 16MB on the website but it is still showing max upload image size of up to 4M as mentioned in the attached file
[image]

This is the max upload size equation in the .htaccess file of root directory:

```
<IfModule php7_module>
   php_flag display_errors Off
   php_value max_execution_time 18000
   php_value max_input_time 600
   php_value max_input_vars 50000
   php_value memory_limit 2048M
   php_value post_max_size 20M
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php71"
   php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
   php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
</IfModule>
```

Can you please tell me how can I make the php.ini file changes in the Magento side with 16M ?

Comment: nginx or apache server?

Comment: It is apache server.

Answer (score 0):

Open your php.ini and make following changes:

- Maximum allowed size for uploaded files **upload_max_filesize = 40M**
- Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
  **post_max_size = 40M**